# How do I run programs in Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, installed-programs

More precisely, what does Ubuntu use instead of Windows' .exe files? For instance, in my last question I asked about Ruby 2.2.2. I want to know which file is the actual Ruby program and all I have is a vague notion of "look in the bin folder".

Comment: That depends on how and where you installed Ruby. Did you install it as shown in the answer (`./configure; make; make install`)? If so, the actual Ruby executable is likely located at `/usr/bin/ruby`. You should be able to run it by just running `ruby` in a terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Linux/Unix doesn't necessarily rely on the extensions like windows does. In other words, a file may already be an executable program. For instance, let's use `which` command that finds the actual binary files for programs and commands, on something like `gnome-terminal`.

```
$ which gnome-terminal
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

As you can see, there's no extension. As far as scripting goes, many users like to add `.sh` and `.py` or even `.awk` ( which i do a lot ), but that's mostly for convenience.

Now, if you have a program and you want to find its binary somewhere on the system, first thing you want to check is `/bin` and `/usr/bin` folder, on any Linux system.

There is however something similar to desktop shortcuts. In `/usr/share/applications/` folder you can find tons of `.desktop` files. That's the second place I'd look into. Unless it's a program you've installed manually, not with Software Center or `apt-get` command, you can be 99% sure that there is a `.desktop` file for that program. Additionally , you can open those files with gedit or any text editor for that matter, and find `Exec=` line to see the actual path to the binary being executed.

So lets recap:

- use `which` command if you know the full command to find where it is stored
- check `/usr/bin/` and `/bin`
- check `/usr/share/applications`

*Additional note:* in order to have a script or a binary file run, it also must have permissions set to `x` (executable) for the owner of the file, group, and/or other users. For instance, I've made a script called `whiletest.sh`. Let's find it's permissions by mixing `ls -l` and `which` command

```
ls -l $(which whiletest.sh )                                                                                                                     
-rwxrwxr-x 1 xieerqi xieerqi 161 May 18 22:42 /home/xieerqi/bin/whiletest.sh
```

So as you can see, we have read-write-execute permissions for the owner(first 3), read-write-execute for the owner group (next 3 ), and read-execute but no write permissions for other users and groups. *These executable permissions aren't given by default when you create a file*. Initial permissions would be `-rw-rw-r--`, ie only read and write access for owner and group. To make any file executable, you'd need to run `chmod 775 /path/to/file` or `chmod +x /path/to/file`. Why two different ways ? You can think of the permissions in terms of binary numbers. So initial permissions `-rw-rw-r--` can be read as 5 for owner (in binary 110, or read set, write set, execute reset), 5 for group, and 4  for others (binary 100, read set, others not set).

For more info on file permissions, you can check [this tutorial from linux.com](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions)

**Additional info about apt-get**:  As requested in the comments, here's more info about `apt-get` . The `apt-get` command is used to install software through command line in terminal. This is what actually Software Center uses behind the scenes to install software.

Personally, I've not used Software Center in a long time, and mostly use `apt-get` like so:

1. Search for a desired program with `apt-cache search`. For instance, `apt-cache search text editor`. If the output is long (and typically it is), I pipe the output to the paging program called `less`, like so. `apt-cache search text editor | less`.
2. Install desired software with `sudo apt-get install program-name`. For example, `sudo apt-get install emacs` .
3. Remove undesirable programs with `sudo apt-get remove program-name` (to just remove a program) or `sudo apt-get purge program-name` (to wipe out every config file as well as the program itself) . For instance, `sudo apt-get remove emacs`.
4. Frequently when you install something, additional packages are installed because a program needs them, but once the program removed , they might not be needed anymore. You can use `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`
5. If you just want the source code of the program, run `sudo apt-get source program-name`. For instance, `sudo apt-get source xterm`

For more things that you can do, check out the [man-page for apt-get](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/apt-get.8.html)

Comment: Maybe add something about the file's permissions, i.e. any file can be executed once it was `chmod +x`-ed. And the OP will most likely recognize the actual binary because AFAIK `make` sets the executable flag by default on the generated binary.

Comment: @the_Seppi added that info

Comment: Could you tell me how to use the apt-get command?

Comment: @JorinGedamke sure ! Just give me a minute or two, I'll edit my answer.  I'll let you know when ready.

Comment: @JorinGedamke done, please check

Comment: Thanks. It looks like Ruby 2.2.2 isn't in the cache; the latest one listed is 1.9.3.

Comment: @JorinGedamke  Yup, it's what's available in the ubuntu repositories for download, but I guess it is a bit outdated.  You've got Ruby installed already or still trying to install it ?  Have you followed the official instructions  ?  http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-ubuntu.html

Comment: Just got Ubuntu installed but deleted Ruby. Here we go again.

Comment: Wow, impressive answer o_O